# Manually store Crowd SSO token in cookie?

Tags: single-sign-on, atlassian-crowd

I'm trying to implement SSO using Atlassian Crowd, and there's a surprising lack of good documentation or even examples out there.

So far, I authenticate a user using **CrowdClient.authenticateSSOUser**, and get back a SSO Token (String) if successful.  Then, I take this token and stuff it in the cookies myself (via HttpServletResponse).  On subsequent page visits, I grab all the cookies, search for this one, and then call the **CrowdClient.validateSSOAuthentication** method on it.

My question is this:  Am I supposed to be using more Crowd code for SSO?  I seem to be doing more manually than I'd expect.

...I DO see hints of other possibilities out there...  For example:

1. In **crowd.properties**, you can specify a **crowd.token_key**, which is apparently what name the app should use store the token in a cookie (though setting this value doesn't magically make that happen).
2. Things like the [CrowdHttpTokenHelper](http://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-crowd/latest/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/http/util/CrowdHttpTokenHelper.html) exist in the latest version - yet seem to have no easily-found related examples (or documentation other than JavaDoc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are possibilities out there that will hopefully help or at least serve as reference.

For a readily available implementation, you might want to look into [Integrating Crowd with Spring Security](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Integrating+Crowd+with+Spring+Security).

If you need finer control, use a [`CrowdHttpAuthenticator`](https://docs.atlassian.com/crowd/current/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/http/CrowdHttpAuthenticator.html). It will allow you to authenticate a request with a username and password as well as check if a session has an existing session cookie. (Its [concrete implementation](https://docs.atlassian.com/crowd/current/com/atlassian/crowd/integration/http/CrowdHttpAuthenticatorImpl.html) will accept properties and uses `crowd.token_key`.)

[`CrowdClient`](https://docs.atlassian.com/crowd/current/com/atlassian/crowd/service/client/CrowdClient.html) is available if these don't fit your needs, but it's not the only option.